# How do you get rid of the NoSuchMethodError below

Tags: flutter

Hello am trying to implement a card flip animation. 
There are three cards according to the below code. I am getting an error 
**NoSuchMethodError** 
*The method '/' was called on null. 
Receiver:null
Tried calling : /(0.333333333)*

The code

```
class _CardFlipperState extends State<CardFlipper> {
double scrollPercent;
Offset startDrag;
double startDragPercentScroll;
double finishScrollStart;
double finishScrollEnd;
AnimationController finishScrollController;

void _onHorizontalDragStart(DragStartDetails details) {
startDrag = details.globalPosition;
startDragPercentScroll = scrollPercent;
}

void _onHorizontalDragUpdate(DragUpdateDetails details) {
final currDrag = details.globalPosition;
final dragDistance = currDrag.dx - startDrag.dx;
final singleCardDragPercent = dragDistance / context.size.width;

final numCards = 3;

setState(() {
  scrollPercent =
      (startDragPercentScroll + (singleCardDragPercent / numCards))
          .clamp(0.0, 1.0 - (1 / numCards));
 });
 }

 void _onHorizontalDragEnd(DragEndDetails details) {


 setState(() {
  startDrag = null;
  startDragPercentScroll = null;
  });
  }

  List<Widget> _buildCards() {
  return [
  _buildCard(0, 3, scrollPercent),
  _buildCard(1, 3, scrollPercent),
  _buildCard(2, 3, scrollPercent),

   ];
   }

   Widget _buildCard(int cardIndex, int cardCount, double scrollPercent) {
   final cardScrollPercent = scrollPercent / (1 / cardCount);
```

The last line seems to be the problem I am just having trouble figuring out why.
Am new on flutter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scrollPercent` is not initialized, init it with something. On the last line dart ends up trying to evaluate `null / 1 / 3`.

Comment: scrollPercent has already been initialized in the first     setState      I dont know if this is the right way to initialise it. Initialising it outside of this function still does not change anything. The error remains

Comment: Did you try initializing the variable at it's declaration `double scrollPercent = 0.0`? The formatting of your code snipped is bad so it's hard to see, but the `setState()` calll which initializes `scrollPercent` is within method `void _onHorizontalDragUpdate(DragUpdateDetails details)`. Are you sure it has been called before `_buildCards()` is called the first time?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you are correct. I had not quite gotten what you meant by initialising        `scrollPercent` . Your answer is correct. Thank You

Comment: The usual is to "accept the answer", if it helped you solve your problem.